# Elementor signup fails

Tags: elementor

[image]

Why can't they deliver email onto my official email, when this email can:

- receive emails
- send emails
- completes every single test on https://mxtoolbox.com

I wish to understand what could I do here to analyse what on Earth is their problem with my email.